# Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, jvm

I added kotlin code into the java project and using JVM VERSION_1_8 so getting this issue "Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 17 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option".

Even i changed JVM to VERSION_17, VERSION_1_8 and VERSION_18 in build.gradle (java), but still having same issue.

Actually my main project is in the java and kotlin code added is local library in it. Please have a look the code screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkBgL.png)

Here is the code
`val flow: Flow<ButtonState> = setNotificationCallback(buttonCharacteristic)             .asValidResponseFlow()`

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle with Java 17?